# how to work around yahoo data issue? Not enough volume to fill

Tags: python, pyalgotrade

I am working on a MACD strategy backtest, and sometimes I came across this warning:

```
2015-02-19 00:00:00 broker.backtesting [DEBUG] Not enough volume to fill 1988.HK market order [1] for 55258 share/s

Then I checked the csv data source and found:
Date        Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj Close
19/02/2015  9.06    9.06    9.06    9.06    0   8.59591
```

as you can see, the `volume` on that particular day was 0, so the order cannot be filled.

I am not going to hack the `pyalgotrade` framework, so is there anyway to work around this? e.g. pre-process the data from `yahoo` feed and set the volume to what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in the strategy constructor:

```
self.getBroker().getFillStrategy().setVolumeLimit(None)
```

Comment: Not working - I placed it into __init__ . Should I place it somewhere else?